# Batch file can't find path to drives other than C

Tags: windows-10, batch

New to all of this*

I'm trying to run three applications from one batch file, two are on E: drive while one is on F: drive. I get a "windows could not find the file" error.

I've allowed full control on all drives, the paths are correct as I copy and pasted them directly.

I tested this on applications on C: drive and they worked (Firefox & Discord)

```
@echo off
cd "E:\PC Stuff\Taco Mod\"
start GW2TacO.exe
cd "E:\PC Stuff\Blish HUD\"
start Blish HUD.exe
cd "F:\Games HDD\Guild Wars 2\"
start Gw2-64.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current drive and current directory are separate things, and each drive can have a different current directory.

CD changes the current directory, and if you specify a drive in the command it sets the directory for that drive, but doesn't change the current drive.

Changing the current drive is done by just specifying the drive letter as a command: `E:`

Your batch file sets the current directory for drive E: to be "\PC Stuff\Taco Mod" but doesn't set E: to be the current drive. You need to set the drive and the directory.

Additionally, because the second command has a space in the name, it needs to be in quotes (thanks @DavidPostill in the comments). But, if the first parameter to the start command has quotes, it's taken to be the window title. So you need to do it like this:

```
@echo off
rem Set current drive to E:
E:
cd "E:\PC Stuff\Taco Mod\"
start GW2TacO.exe
cd "E:\PC Stuff\Blish HUD\"
start "" "Blish HUD.exe"
rem Set current drive to F:
F:
cd "F:\Games HDD\Guild Wars 2\"
start Gw2-64.exe
exit
```

Comment: It's easier to use the `/d` option - ie `cd /d "E:\PC Stuff\Taco Mod\"`

Comment: I always forget that. Knowing what's happening and why, it's clearer to me to do the two steps separately.

Comment: Great thanks for the replies! It seems to load two of the three (for some reason is cannot find Blish HUD.exe (though the error only says windows cannot find Blish, is there an issue with there being a space in the name?)

Comment: @Ashh `start "" "Blish HUD.exe"`

Comment: That worked! Legend thank you! Again, I'm new to this, if you have time could you explain why that worked that way? I'd love to learn about it

Comment: If the first parameter to start has quotes, it's the window title, so you have to have the blank string in there to put the command in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you can try **[`start /d "D:\Path" "title" "program.exe"`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)**

```bath
@echo off

start /d "E:\PC Stuff\Taco Mod\" "GW2TacO" "GW2TacO.exe"
start /d "E:\PC Stuff\Blish HUD\" "Blish HUD" "Blish HUD.exe"
start /d "F:\Games HDD\Guild Wars 2\" "Gw2-64" "Gw2-64.exe"
exit
```